# Not able to use MediaQuery in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Upgraded my Flutter 3 days ago.

I'm not able to use `MediaQuery.of(context)`, terminal shows an error:

> No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.

Comment: You need to give more details, if you are using null safety you might need to use `MediaQueryData? data = MediaQuery.maybeOf(context);`

Comment: can you write your code in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide us with any code, so I am going to assume that you didn't wrap the `Material` class with the `MaterialApp` widget. Like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home : MyHomePage()));
//wrap the MyHomePage widget with MaterialApp
```

I hope this answer would help.